# sudo vi /usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions not allowing to sav ethe file

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am editing the file to add sub version

```
    To install for all users, copy RabbitVCS.py to:
    /usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions

 Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\RabbitVCS.py,\~$
```

Buty while saving its showing error

```
E45: 'readonly' option is set (add ! to override)
```

Tried command

```
:w ! sudo tee %
```

But not allowing to save bcz of directory

Answer (score 0):

Maybe chattr attribute is set ? 
 Check it `lsattr /usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions`. If `i` is present in the output unset it `chattr -i /usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions`